# Pycharm: Avoid Line Break After Semicolon When Reformatting

Tags: python, pycharm

In Pycharm, I have a multiline Python command like (that I generate by a live template by the way):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.plot(A);plt.show()
```

I do not want to have it splitted in three single lines when I execute `Menu - Code - Reformat Code`.

The reason for this is, that I want to have a concise and compact way of printing the contents of a variable (so also `@formatter:on` won't be a solution)

How can I avoid the split in three consecutive lines by the reformatting tool?

Comment: What are these `;` ??

Comment: Can't have the cake and eat it too. Why not add comment blocks before and after?
If you insist on it being on the same line, comment it out -> reformat code -> then uncomment the line. If you don't want to do this, invest in rewriting the reformatter for this specific case

Comment: @ArashHatami: Semicolons are statement separators in Python. *Language Reference:* A simple statement is comprised within a single logical line. Several simple statements may occur on a single line separated by semicolons. They are mostly there to make life easier for C programmers. But they do (as in this case) have other uses.

Comment: @Usernamenotfound : do you have a starting point (url to a documentation or tutorial etc.) for me how I could rewrite a reformatter for this specific situation?

Comment: `I want to have a concise and compact way of printing the contents of a variable` - why not make it a function? It could be even more compact/concise...

Comment: @DanCornilescu I had this thought already. But my aim is to use the live templates "ad hoc": So if I have the question how the data looks like: call this single life template and visualize it. Therefore I also have the import statement in the referring line.... it would be cool if Pycharm would offer "inline functions" that hide complex and lenghty code when just calling them adhoc.

Comment: The formatter should 1) remove all semicolons followed by newlines, 2) remove all newlines after the remaining semicolons.